# How do I set the height of an editor in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, editor, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create an app that has an editor and I was not able to successfully set the height for the editor field. Basically it is a feedback form kind of thing and I want users to be able to see more than one line of text that they are typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Editor](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Editor/) is a control that can edit multiple lines of text.

You can set the height by `HeightRequest` property. Read about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.HeightRequestProperty/).

From Code :

```
var descriptionEntry = new Editor { HeightRequest = 50 };
```

From XAML :

```
<Editor HeightRequest = "50" />
```

You have more samples on Editor [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor/).

Comment: Height property is readonly. I tried the HeightRequest property, but looks like it is not taking it.   `Editor descriptionEntry = new Editor();
            descriptionEntry.HeightRequest = 50;`

Comment: The HeightRequest property finally seem to have done it. Thank you. Don't know why it did not work earlier.